# impossible to change button place

Tags: html, css, button

`enter code here`I try to clone twitter news feed.in profile section try to recreate edit profile button: .editprofile , but unfortunately for some reason I cant move my element right ,  in the end of the box , under cover photo.
I used display:flex and flex-direction:column , beside that when I am using align-items:end nothing changes.

html code:

```html
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="nav-box">
              <div class="nav-grid">
                <ion-icon class="twitter-logo" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                <nav class="main-nav">
                  <ul class="main-nav-list">
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="home-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="earth-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Explore</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon
                        class="nav-icon"
                        name="notifications-outline"
                      ></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="mail-open-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Messages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="bookmark-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Bookmarks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon
                        class="nav-icon"
                        name="document-text-outline"
                      ></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Lists</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="person-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon
                        class="nav-icon"
                        name="ellipsis-horizontal-circle-outline"
                      ></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">More</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <a class="btn-Tweet" href="#">Tweet</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-box">
              <div class="name-attributes">
                <ion-icon
                  class="main-box-arrow"
                  name="arrow-back-outline"
                ></ion-icon>
                <div class="name-attribute">
                  <p class="main-box-name">James Holland</p>
                  <p class="main-box-tweets">1,789 Tweets</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="main-box-profile">
                <img
                  class="profile-cover"
                  src="subscription1.png"
                  ref="profile cover photo"
                />
                <img class="profile-img" src="ben.jpg" ref="profile photo" />
                <div class="main-edit-profile">
                  <a class="edit-profile" href="#">Edit profile</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="side-box">asdfg</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
```

css code:

```css
    .main-box {
    border-width: thin;
    border-left: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
  }

.main-box-name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  }

  .main-box-tweets {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
}

  .main-box-arrow {
  color: #fff;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

  .main-box-arrow:hover {
  color: #0db924;
}

  .name-attributes {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

  .main-box .main-box-profile {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  .profile-cover {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
}


  .profile-img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(10%, 75%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

  .main-box-profile .edit-profile {
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
  align-items: end;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-edit-profile {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Try this.and no need of `position:absolute` for **.main-box-profile .edit-profile** class

Comment: yes , but then it gives border on whole block not exactly on button. how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-box {
    border-width: thin;
    border-left: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
  }

.main-box-name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  }

  .main-box-tweets {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #777;
}

  .main-box-arrow {
  color: #fff;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

  .main-box-arrow:hover {
  color: #0db924;
}

  .name-attributes {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

  .main-box .main-box-profile {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }

  .profile-cover {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
}


  .profile-img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(10%, 75%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

  .main-box-profile .edit-profile {
    /* position: absolute; */
    text-decoration: none;
  align-items: end;
  color: #f00000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
      border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .main-edit-profile {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="nav-box">
              <div class="nav-grid">
                <ion-icon class="twitter-logo" name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                <nav class="main-nav">
                  <ul class="main-nav-list">
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="home-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="earth-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Explore</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon
                        class="nav-icon"
                        name="notifications-outline"
                      ></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="mail-open-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Messages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="bookmark-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Bookmarks</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon
                        class="nav-icon"
                        name="document-text-outline"
                      ></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Lists</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon class="nav-icon" name="person-outline"></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <ion-icon
                        class="nav-icon"
                        name="ellipsis-horizontal-circle-outline"
                      ></ion-icon
                      ><a class="main-nav-link" href="#">More</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
                <a class="btn-Tweet" href="#">Tweet</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-box">
              <div class="name-attributes">
                <ion-icon
                  class="main-box-arrow"
                  name="arrow-back-outline"
                ></ion-icon>
                <div class="name-attribute">
                  <p class="main-box-name">James Holland</p>
                  <p class="main-box-tweets">1,789 Tweets</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="main-box-profile">
                <img
                  class="profile-cover"
                  src="subscription1.png"
                  ref="profile cover photo"
                />
                <img class="profile-img" src="ben.jpg" ref="profile photo" />
                <div class="main-edit-profile">
                  <a class="edit-profile" href="#">Edit profile</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="side-box">asdfg</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve.I had added border to the button.

```
.main-box-profile .edit-profile {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```